# Why $V\propto R$ and $V\propto I$?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

Ohm's law's gives us two relations: $V\propto R$ and $V\propto I$. But why is that so?

Potential difference($V$) between two points depends on the concentration of charges between them. Current flows from a region of high concentration of electrons to low concentration of electrons(low to high potential). But I can't seem to figure out how $V$ is dependent on:

- **Current($I$):** According to my book-

> Potential difference between two points is equal to the work done *per unit charge* in moving a positive test charge from one point to another.

So why does current, which is number of charges flowing per unit time a factor in the work done on *unit* charge? If the work done on a unit charge to bring it from one point to another is $x$ then the work done to move $5$ charges between the same points is $5x$, but the potential between the two points, as per the definition, remains $x$.

- **Resistance($R$)-**

Suppose there is unit positive charge Q which is being taken to a greater positively charged body.
[image]

Suppose external work done is $x$ and then some resistance is provided in the path of the charge.
We know that $$\Delta W_{external}=\Delta PE + \Delta KE + W_{other}$$ where $W_{other}$ comprises other forms in which energy is being lost, e.g., heat, against friction, etc. So isn't work done against resistance coming under $W_{other}$? Just like in gravitational potential energy, where if we lift a body up a certain height through air, then stop the ball and keept it at rest at that certain height, then $W_{external}=\Delta PE+ \Delta KE + W_{againstresistance}$. $\Delta KE$ is $0$, and the total external work done is $\Delta PE + W_{againstresistance}$, but the change in potential always remains $mg \Delta y$!

Then why is the potential difference not only dependent on the shortest distance between and the charge concentration of the two points, but instead on $I$ and $R$?

Comment: I think you're drawing too much from the fact cases share the word potential. Especially in in your gravity example you just stop the block from falling any farther whereas in the electrical current case the current must take the path through the resistor. A fair example would be you stop the block from falling and push it sideways overcoming friction. In that case, you aren't changing the gravitational potential, but you're needing to add energy from somewhere to push it sideways. If you tried harnessing gravitational potential to move it sideways you would have to be falling somehow as well.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I considered in the gravitational potential energy case. I am not causing the object to fall under gravity, I am raising it against gravity, and there is air resistance(which I am comparing with resistance in case of electric potential) @DKNguyen

Comment: That last example doesn't sound any different than charging a battery to me. If you push current into a battery you have to provide some energy. But some of that energy will be lost in the resistor on its way into the battery so the battery won't end up with all the energy you supplied. Just like how your raised object only contains mgh at the end, and not mgh+air resistance.

Comment: Are you just hung up on the distinction between KE and Wother in an electrical circuit? TBH, I don't much care for that distinction. To me, it's just stored energy and the energy doing work. Or, with regards to your last sentence: We use wires because it provides an easier path than through free space. The shortest path doesn't necessarily mean the easiest path. The shortest path could take far more work than another path.

Comment: @DKNguyen "Just like how your raised object only contains mgh at the end, and not mgh+air resistance." Yeah, and that is why I thought that the potential difference between the two points should be the only the work done(say, $W_b$) to bring the body towards another charge without acceleration. And resistance in the battery is just leading to the battery doing more work $W_b+W_r$ but out of that, only $W_b$ should be stored in the charge as potential right? After all, any kind of potential(which I know of) depends only on change in _position_ of the body in a field(here, electric field)

Comment: If you're basing these thoughts on the electric field then you can't ignore the fact that the electric wave constructs itself to travel around the wire which is an easier path than through the air. The picture is incomplete otherwise.

Comment: @DKNguyen so the electric field is affected by the resistance, due to which the potential is too?

Comment: In your question, for current and voltage, which are you treating as the manipulated variable and which are you treating as the responding variable? Because in electronics, most of the time we use voltage sources and current is the one that is affected by resistance but in your question you seem to be talking about potential being affected instead.

Comment: @DKNguyen i am afraid i am not aware of the terms you used in the latest comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132583/discussion-between-dknguyen-and-mehmer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For many physics problems the way to solve them is to get the right level of abstraction. You have drifted into the wrong level.

You need to be careful about comparing currents in wires to motion of particles affected by potential differences on static charges. Your diagram shows a test charge being moved from infinity towards a fixed charge. Electric circuits are not like that. Ohms law is about circuits.

As a snap-you-out-of-your-rut consideration, consider an electron going around a circuit several times. It moves "up" the resistance each time. Does it therefore wind up at a higher potential each time? Or does something happen so that it gets back down the hill each time?

The potential difference between the leads of a resistor determine the energy a single electron will *dissipate* in the resistor as it goes through. It does not gain that much energy. On the other side of the resistor it will have pretty much the same energy it had in the wire before the resistor. It will be stumping along at the same speed it had before.

The electron is getting pushed through the resistor. The restance is using up the energy of that push, mostly as heat. Tiny bit of electromagetic radiation.

When you increase the potential, increasing V, more current flows. And each electron loses *more* energy passing through the resistor. Double V you also double I, and you multiply the power into the resistor by 4. They do go faster, but the kinetic energy in an electron is quite small compared to the energy the current is carrying.

So your diagram of bringing a test charge from infinity is misplaced. You want to think of the electrons on a string getting dragged across rough surfaces. They don't wind up with more energy even if you pull harder. You just get more per second going by any given spot. And by pulling harder each one gets more violently smacked around by the rough surface.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for an more intuitive understanding then maybe look at 'cause and effect'

A circuit with 0 voltage at any point evidently has no current flowing.

A potential difference provides a 'push' (the water pressure analogy DOES work here) to make the current flow.

It seems intuitive that the harder you push the more will flow. Ohms law simply formulates that the relationship is linear.

So rather than think of  V∝I it is more the case that  I∝V.

Whilst they are mathematically equivalent the second suggests more clearly that current is caused by the PD.

Comment: "Whilst they are mathematically equivalent the second suggests more clearly that current is caused by the PD." Current creates voltage drop and voltage creates current.Both are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Voltage - energy required to bring a charged particle from infinity to a specific field/region.
Mathematical formulation : $$V=-\int_\infty^a \vec E\cdot \mathrm d\vec r$$ In circuit- we take two points between a resistance(considering the circuit is series circuit). Cause there's some energy lost for resistance. Resistance converts some sort of energy to heat. $$P=I^2R$$ to derive the equation you can apply two equations $$P=\frac{W}{t}\tag{1}$$ $$W=VQ$$

Current- amount of charge flow in a specific region per sec(the definition in your book is also correct)($I=V/R$). Math :$$I=\frac{q}{t}$$

In 18th, 19th or 17th centuries an experimentalist had done a work with flow of current. He observed as, voltage increases the rate of charge flows also increases. For different materials the value was different, he had drawn a graph potential vs current. he found straight line for all materials. That's why he thought $$I\propto V$$. Further he thought something is stopping flow of charges which was called resistance and since it is decreasing flow of charges that's why resistance is inversely proportional to current $$I=V/R$$